# Splitting order list magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

i am using magento 1.7.In my store i am giving an free product for all the products.If i add the product, free product will also be added with the main product to the cart.All main product and free products appearing in same order list at the back end sales .I need all the free product in one order list and main products in another order list.And Order number should be same for both the free product list and main product list.Same to invoice and shipping also.Please suggest me how to go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

http://niharika09.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/to-split-orders-in-magento-based-on-backorders/

here instead of the back order products or products that have less than 0 quantity you can use the particular product id you want and manipulate accordingly.

Comment: I checked with it..Didn't work out.What i have to in adminhtml.xml and system.xml

Comment: thats not needed if you remove the $isEnabled = Mage::getStoreConfig('splitorders/splitorder/manage_splitorder'); and change the if condition to if ($backOrder)

Comment: removed $isEnabled and changed if condition also...My File structure is app/code/local/Split/Splitorder/etc/config.xml and app/code/local/Split/Splitorder/Model/observer.php

Comment: config.xml                                                         <events>

<sales_convert_quote_to_order>
<observers>
<namespace_split_order>
<class>Split_Splitorder_Model_Observer</class>
<method>splitOrder</method>
</namespace_split_order>
</observers>
</sales_convert_quote_to_order>

</events>

Comment: it should be Observer.php i.e capital O

Comment: you will also need to change code this code splits back order products with in order products